# Have no excute permission on my hard disk

Tags: permissions, mount

I'm new to Ubuntu. In order to mount the hard disk, I added the following line to `/etc/fstab` and saved it.

```
/dev/sda1 /home/mine/hd1 ext4 auto,exec,users,rw  0 0
```

output of `sudo fdisk -l`：

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1BE4FADE-5038-4B8E-BA1A-11E38749A593

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 7814035455 7814033408  3.7T Linux filesystem




Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 46108040-B863-4181-94EF-8DEEF7ACD4D5

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2    1050624 201078783 200028160 95.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  201078784 234440703  33361920 15.9G Linux swap
```

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=e4488cf9-7c51-4456-8626-bfe96ba919a8 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=3144-2FF0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=4189137f-17b2-484c-83a9-8ca406d68cad none            swap    sw   0       0
/dev/sda1 /home/cpl/hd1 ext4 auto,exec,users,rw  0 0
```

However, I find it does not work after I reboot. For example, I want to run `/home/cpl/hd1/a.out` and it shows

```
bash: /home/cpl/hd1/a.out: Permission denied
```

I tried the command `chmod`, but failed.

How can I get all permissions?
(p.s. I find that if I delete the line I added to `/etc/fstab` and run `sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/hd1`, I will get excute permission. The thing is you need run it again every time you boot.)
Here are the output of `sudo ls -alh ~/hd1` before and after I exectue `sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/hd1`.

Before:

```
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x  2 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  4 17:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  5 10:22 ..
```

After:

```
total 44K
drwsr-xr-x  8 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  5 00:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  5 10:22 ..
drwsr-xr-x  2 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  4 18:53 beifen
drwsr-xr-x  3 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  4 20:37 fanqiang
drwsr-xr-x  2 cpl cpl  16K Sep  1 14:02 lost+found
drwsr-xr-x  2 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  4 16:01 test
drwsr-xr-x  5 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  3 20:25 .Trash-1000
drwsr-xr-x  2 cpl cpl 4.0K Sep  4 21:00 utorrent
```

Comment: Could you please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question (please [edit] it)? Is this an external hard drive? Could you show us your whole `fstab`?

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo ls -alh ~/hd1` before and after you exectue `sudo mount /dev/sda1 ~/hd1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed it out but forgot to record here. Actually I just made a little change to the line I had added to `/etc/fstab` :

```
/dev/sda1 /home/cpl/hd1 ext4 auto,users,exec,rw  0 0
```

The thing is  `users` should be in front of `exec`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add ,uid=1001 to those options (assuming youruser ID in /etc/passwd is 1001)

```
/dev/sda1 /home/mine/hd1 ext4 auto,exec,users,rw,uid=1001 0 0
```

Worked for me.

Comment: After that I reboot and enter the emergency mode (mine uid is 1000)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is `auto` will auto mount using the `uid` value (user id) as the owner of the filesystem. Since you have`auto` but no `uid` it will use default `0` which is root.

why it works before the reboot? because you set `users`, which allow regular users to mount the device. When a regular user mounts it, the default value for uid is the current user's. So when you mount it, you own the filesystem, when you boot with auto mount, root owns the filesystem.

just add `uid=1000`. type in `id` to see your user uid.

---

other option is to fix the permissions on the file to not depend on the filesystem root inheritance.

after mounting as root, which is correct for ext* filesystems, type `sudo chmod a+x /mnt/my/file` so everyone canexecute that file. Alternatively learn unix permisions and add group execution to matchyour user(s) group.

Comment: I doubt that `auto` will do what you describe. From the man page: *Can be mounted with the -a option.*. And `uid` is not an ext4 option but rather NTFS.

Comment: Yeah. I tried both and failed . Uid is not an ext4 option but rather NTFS, which made me enter the emergency mode.  Chmod didn't work either.

Comment: use 'ls -lan' and compare to your userid. maybe there is another uid with the same username?